# Execute Commands With Pipe Using SSH command

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line

I am using bash script to execute command line with pipe after SSH.

I want to do this flow :

-> ssh to server (using key)

-> go to specific directory

-> `more file.txt | grep string`.

.

so, I am using this script below:

`ssh -i key.txt user@address -p 22 "cd /some/path/to/directory ; more file.txt ; grep string "`

But, instead of grep the string, it only execute `more file.txt`.

How can I do command with pipe after SSH ?

Comment: Did you try `ssh -i key.txt user@address -p 22 "cd /some/path/to/directory ; grep string file.txt"` ?

Comment: Hi anishsane, yes I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you meant to type a `|` character instead of a `;` between `more file.txt` and `grep string`.

Comment: @ferori : It does not make sense to feed the output of a pager (`more`) into the stdin of another program. If the file being viewed by `more` has less lines than the terminal size, it would simply act as `cat`. Also I don't see that you are using any pipe in the one-line-`ssh`-script you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you do not need to execute this sequence of operations. Just try this:

```
ssh -i key.txt user@address -p 22 "grep string /some/path/to/directory/file.txt"
```